# Using MEMBER OF for a persisted entity and persisted entity collection

Tags: collections, jpql, contains

```
SELECT d
FROM YYY d
WHERE d MEMBER OF :parameter.myCollection
```

What is wrong with that query? parameter is an entity I retrieve from the database in a previous step. I keep getting the following exception:

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "d MEMBER OF :" at character 18, but expected: ["(", "*", "+", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INDEX", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "KEY", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "VALUE", "WHERE", , , , , , , , , ]." while parsing JPQL "SELECT d
    FROM YYY d
    WHERE d MEMBER OF :parameter.myCollection
". See nested stack trace for original parse error.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:672)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:654)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:620)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:589)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1037)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1016)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
SELECT d
FROM YYY d
WHERE d IN :parameter.myCollection
```

An explanation of how to use 'MEMBER OF' and 'IN' is [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection)

Comment: The problem is that :parameter is an entity and myCollection is a collection field in that entity. So it's somehow a mix of MEMBER OF and IN usage. I am not sure whether JPQL can deal with that at all.

Comment: I tried with IN before I asked the question, but the result was the same error.